# Не обновляетс файлы hotreload webpack(Update failed: ChunkLoadError: Loading hot update chunk app failed.)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Обновил webpack4 до webpack5

Выходит сообщение в консоль браузера при изменении файла при разработке и hotreload webpack dev server. Т.е. при запуске npm start все работает хорошо, но как только я изменю что-то в любом файле, то выходит это сообщение:

```
Update failed: ChunkLoadError: Loading hot update chunk app failed.
```

Моя конфигурация webpack.config.ts

```
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin from 'html-webpack-harddisk-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const nodeEnv = (process.env.NODE_ENV as 'development' | 'production' | 'none') || 'development';
const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';
const pathList = {
  dist: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/build'),
  public: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www'),
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
};

const getModePlugins = () => {
  return isProd
    ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
          dry: false,
          verbose: true,
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: 'styles.[contenthash:5].min.css',
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
      ]
    : [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()];
};

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: nodeEnv,

  entry: {
    app: path.resolve('src/'),
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[fullhash:5].min.js',
    path: pathList.dist,
    publicPath: '/build/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.es', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    modules: [pathList.src, path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      filename: path.resolve(pathList.public, './index.html'),
      inject: true,
      template: path.resolve(pathList.src, './index.htm'),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(),
    ...getModePlugins(),
  ],

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[hash:5].[ext]' },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(es|ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|lib/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { cacheDirectory: true },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(es|ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:5].[ext]' },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        use: ['url-loader?limit=5000&name=images/build/[name].[ext]'],
      },
      {
        test: /.*\.svg$/i,
        use: [
          '@svgr/webpack',
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: 'img/[name].[hash:5].[ext]' },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  devServer: isProd
    ? {}
    : {
        contentBase: pathList.public,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true,
        port: 8000,
      },

  devtool: isProd ? false : 'eval',
};

export default config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.ts",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx src --fix",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.8",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.3.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free": "^2.7.0",
    "@turf/boolean-contains": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/difference": "^6.0.2",
    "@turf/kinks": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.8",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.12",
    "@types/leaflet-geosearch": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^2.5.2",
    "@types/react-leaflet-markercluster": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
    "antd": "^4.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "http-status": "^1.5.0",
    "leaflet": "1.6.0",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^2.7.0",
    "leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.uniqueid": "^4.0.1",
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.5",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.1.6",
    "mobx-react-router": "^4.1.0",
    "mobx-utils": "^6.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "point-in-polygon": "^1.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.13.8",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-baron": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
    "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.21",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.26",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.13.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "import-sort": "^6.0.0",
    "import-sort-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "less": "^4.1.0",
    "less-loader": "^7.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.14.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, нужно изменить webpack.config.ts

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      ...
    },
```

},